# Using D3.js geom to scale a voronoi polygon with result in lat long, not coordinates in px

Tags: javascript, d3.js, polygons, geography, voronoi

I am trying to create voronoi polygons for a set of inputs points in lat/long. The problem is my input dataset can contain multiple points at the same location and hence the same voronoi polygons are returned for that point.

I would like to visually display the overlapping polygons (with each polygon slightly smaller than the previous) to demonstrate that there are multiple polygons at the same point as per the screenshot below.

From reading the documentation, it seems that you can scale projections but these projections are already in px, not my real world lat/long values.

So, how can I take an input polygon in lat/long and return a polygon that is shrunk by X%, with the output polygon in lat/long using d3.js-v3?

Example polygon input: [long1, lat1, long2, lat2, long3, lat3, long4, lat4]

[image: concentric polygons]

edit: the above image is using a "clip" function to clip the polygons with ever shrinking clip radiuses, which gives the desired effect for edge polygons, but does not achieve the desired effect for internally bound polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was quite easy in the end.

```
var p1 = d3.geom.polygon(polygonArray);
var centroid = p1.centroid();
var newPolygonArray = [];
p1.forEach(function(v, i) {  
    var newLong = centroid[0] + (v[0] - centroid[0])*(0.9);
    var newLat = centroid[1] + (v[1] - centroid[1])*(0.9);
    newPolygonArray.push(newLong, newLat);
}.bind(this));
```

I spent far too long trying to use d3 functions and projections to transform, translate and scale the polygon, but as soon as I left work that day it hit me that all I needed to do was the simple maths procedure above.

The lesson is to take a break when you are stuck, fresh air can open your eyes.

[concentric voronoi polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTit2.jpg)